# running Tornado and Nginx on same server

Tags: web-applications, nginx, tornado

I have a static website served up by nginx right now, and I want to develop an app with Tornado on the same server.

The Tornado documentation mentions that wsgi doesn't support non-blocking requests.

Is there a way for me to get them to work together (on the same server)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure you can. Take a look at the [nginx.conf example on tornado's homepage](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/overview.html?highlight=nginx#running-tornado-in-production).

The relevant bits in your case would be:

```
http {
    # Enumerate all the Tornado servers here
    upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;
        server 127.0.0.1:8002;
        server 127.0.0.1:8003;
    }
    ...
    server {
        ...
        # for your "static" website
        location ^~ /static/ {
            root /var/www;
            if ($query_string) {
                expires max;
            }
        }
        # for your tornado's app
        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect false;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I read that, but those would be different servers (different ip addresses) right? I think sockets are the way to go, I need to look into it more.

Comment: Not at all. You can have the same server serving different applications... For example, on my personal website, I've got a 2 wordpress blogs and a python app all served from the same webserver. They are configured to respond to requests to different urls (for example `http://myserver/app`, `http://myserver/wp1`, `http://myserver/wp2`. Then I have redirects to point, for example, `http://wonderful-blog.com` -> `http://myserver/wp1`. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I think so. To clarify, the tornado instances listen to the 8000, 8001, 8002, 8003 ports?

Comment: Correct. You've got 4 tornado instances running on ports 8000..8003 and nginx load balancing requests on them.

Comment: The nginx.conf link is broken, so I figured I would provide the current working link for sake of convenience. Hope this helps someone. http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/overview.html?highlight=nginx#running-tornado-in-production

Comment: Links (from reply and comment) are broken. Updated one: http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#running-behind-a-load-balancer